# VssUnauthorizedException VS30063 You are not authorized to access error suddenly thrown

Tags: c#, azure-devops

i have the following code that uses VSTS Client Side API's that was working but now returns an error of:
**Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssUnauthorizedException: 'VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://XXXXXX.visualstudio.com.**

Here is the current C# code:

```
var vstsUrl = "https://XXXXXX.visualstudio.com";

var vssClientCred = new VssClientCredentials
{
  Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage(),
  PromptType = 
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.CredentialPromptType.PromptIfNeeded
 };

var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(vstsUrl), vssClientCred);
var projectHttpClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
var listOfProjects  = projectHttpClient.GetProjects().Result;
```

The error gets thrown when an attempt to the GetClient method is invoked.

Here is what I have tried so far with no luck:

- Sign out of web portal for VSTS
- Clear browser cache
- Tested whether I have access to VSTS through Visual Studio 2017 in the web browser window,  I can successfully log in
- Sign out of the account
- Clear browser cache
- Restart Visual Studio 2017
- Restart the machine*

The code works on a different machine that is running Visual Studio 2017 so I don't think it's my user account. After it worked on that machine, I cleared the browser etc on that machine and went back to my main machine, tried the code again and the error still gets thrown.

Any ideas what else I can try to resolve the error?

Comment: Did you try rebooting your machine?

Comment: Tried this and unfortunately, it didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your user account can access to the VSTS account, then please **clean the cached credentials in VS** and run your code again. Detail steps as below:

Execute `regedit` -> clean key(s) under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio\VssApp` -> restart VS -> run your project with your own credential.