# Azure DevOps Client SDK: Using TestManagementHttpClient.GetTestResultsByBuildAsync2 throws auth error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sdk-.net

I am using the [.NET client library for Azure DevOps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/16.199.0-preview) to get test results from a build attempt. The following throws an authentication error, `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssUnauthorizedException: VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com.`

```cs
var testClient = connection.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();

var testResults = await testClient.GetTestResultsByBuildAsync2(
                project: project,
                buildId: ID);
```

I am using a PAT that is scoped to read and execute Builds and Tests. Not sure why I'm getting this error. Is there another way to get test results per attempt? I am able to use this same connection to call `GetTestResultDetailsForBuildAsync` but unfortunately, that lists results for all the attempts and I just need the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Try either of the following ways to resolve `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssUnauthorizedException: VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com.` error:

> 1. Clean the cache as suggested by [Marina Liu:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878334/vssunauthorizedexception-vs30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-error-suddenly)Execute
>    `regedit` -> clean key(s) under
>    `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio\VssApp`
>    -> restart VS -> run your project with your own credential.
> 2. Check whether Personal Access Token has expired or created with the right Scope or not

References: [VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com? Error while trying to register Private agent Pool in Azure DevOps Project using PAT token - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/272411/vs30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-httpsdeva.html) , [c# - VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57766867/vs30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-https-dev-azure-com) and [Visual Studio Feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-httpsdeva-2/1532255)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and none of the suggestions helped. I was also able to call some other methods but not the `GetTestResultsByBuildAsync`.
Luckily, I have noticed that there are different types of clients:

```cs
TestResultsHttpClient testClient1 = connection.GetClient<TestResultsHttpClient>(); 
TestManagementHttpClient testClient2 = connection.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();
```

Then calling the code below worked fine if I used `testClient1` and failed with an authentication error when I used `testClient2`.:

```
List<ShallowTestCaseResult> allTestResults =
   await testClient.GetTestResultsByBuildAsync(ProjectName, buildId);
```

Please try to use `TestResultsHttpClient` instead of `TestManagementHttpClient`.